# How to click in an input element in a HTML using Selenium with Python 3.8

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I m pretty new to Selenium with Python...

Anyways I got the following HTML in which I want to locate and click on the **"Search field"** in Python 3.8:

```
<input class="XTCLo x3qfX" type="text" autocapitalize="none" placeholder="Suchen" value=""/>
```

I already tried these following steps:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Search']")` by **XPath**.

`driver.find_element_by_class_name("XTCLo x3qfX")` by **class name**.

None of the above-listed steps worked for me, so I would love to hear solutions :D

Python version: **3.8.2**.
Chrome version for automation: **81.0.4044.138**.

Comment: What is your error message? Post it inside the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What's the result with the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

And :

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@autocapitalize]")))
element.click();
```